# How to determine indices in array between a set of values (in batch)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, numba

I was wondering if anyone has an idea on how to speed up the identification of which indices are between a set of values.

Let's say I have a 1d array of sorted values (~50k) and a large list (>100k) of a pair of min/max values and I want to determine which (if any) indices in the 1d array are present. I must also be able to do this many times where the 1d array changes in size/shape.

My current approach is to use `numpy` and `numba` and `list comprehension` but unfortunately it doesn't really scale. It's okay if I try to look for ~1k values but when the number is much larger, it's too slow to be able to repeat it 1000s of times.

Current code:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit()
def find_between_batch(array: np.ndarray, min_value: np.ndarray, max_value: np.ndarray):
    """Find indices between specified boundaries for many items."""
    res = []
    for i in range(len(min_value)):
        res.append(np.where(np.logical_and(array >= min_value[i], array <= max_value[i]))[0])
    return res
```

Here is an example of the input:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 2000, 50000) # input 1d array

# these are the boundaries for which we should find the indices
mins = np.sort(np.random.choice(x, 10000)) - 0.01  # lower values to search for
maxs = mins + 0.02  # upper values to search for
```

And the current performance

```py
# pre-compile
result = find_between_batch(x, mins, maxs)
%timeit -r 3 -n 10 find_between_batch(x, mins, maxs)
616 ms ± 4.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And example output

```
result

[array([11]),
 array([14]),
 array([19]),
 array([23]),
 ...
]
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to speed this up or if there is another approach that could give me the same results?

Comment: A little example (input and output) would help with understanding.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the question and split the example data + example output

Comment: `np.searchsorted(x, mins)`?

Comment: What do you want to do if no element in the array is between min and max? Or will this not happen?

Comment: I see an example output but not its example input.

Comment: @MechanicPig In the example data there is no such example but if there are no elements between the min/max then it should be returned as empty array or list.

Comment: @KellyBundy The example data is above the "And the current performance" section ```x = np.linspace(0, 2000, 50000) # input 1d array

# these are the boundaries for which we should find the indices
mins = np.sort(np.random.choice(x, 10000)) - 0.01  # lower values to search for
maxs = mins + 0.02  # upper values to search for```

Comment: That's code to produce data. I don't see the data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion to use `np.searchsorted` - I've come up with a solution that is approx. 10-100x faster than my initial attempt.

```py
@numba.njit()
def find_between_batch2(array: np.ndarray, min_value: np.ndarray, max_value: np.ndarray):
    """Find indices between specified boundaries for many items."""
    min_indices = np.searchsorted(array, min_value, side="left")
    max_indices = np.searchsorted(array, max_value, side="right")

    res = []
    for i in range(len(min_value)):
        _array = array[min_indices[i]:max_indices[i]]
        res.append(min_indices[i] + find_between(_array, min_value[i], max_value[i]))
    return res
```

Original code:

```
%timeit -r 3 -n 10 find_between_batch(x, mins, maxs)
616 ms ± 4.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Updated code:

```
%timeit -r 3 -n 10 find_between_batch2(x, mins, maxs)
6.36 ms ± 73.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
```